# Converting h2o model results to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, h2o

I am training a model in h2o like so:

```
import h2o

h2o.init()
trainFrame = h2o.import_file(path = "C:/train.csv")

train, test = trainFrame.split_frame([0.8])

x = ["A", "B", "C"]
y = "Target"

m = h2o.estimators.H2ORandomForestEstimator(model_id="RF_defaults")
m.train(x, y, train)
```

now I want to save these results to a pandas dataframe.

I am trying to do that like so:

`m.as_data_frame(pandas = True)`

but that returns:

`AttributeError: type object 'H2ORandomForestEstimator' has no attribute 'as_data_frame'`

Comment: Well, yes. You have to call it on a h2o frame, not a model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model object `m` has a lot of information in it.  Use `dir(m)` to see all of the available components.

In some cases, a component of `m` is already stored as a data frame, such as the Scoring History:

```
type(m.scoring_history())
# <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

In other cases, a component will be a list of values, such as Variable Importance:

```
type(m.varimp())
# <type 'list'>
```

So, have a look at the output of `m`, decide what you want, call it with the method names in `dir(m)`, and then convert to data frame as needed.